# How can I figure out the DNS nameservers of client connected to Express server?

Tags: node.js, express, dns

I would like to create a command-line DNS leak tool that would be queried using a cURL GET request but have no clue how to get client DNS nameservers.

Trying to figure out how this is done on https://ipleak.net/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a custom DNS server to do this.

It looks like that tool generates a bunch of random DNS entries that need to be resolved, then tracks which DNS server IPs ask for those records.

For example, when I ran the test I got this entry:

```
w10zp1nbxt8uhf7le9rmr91l2zbw4ml7rt0na3ql.ipleak.net
```

By tracking which server(s) access this name you can roughly determine where the DNS queries originate.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for helping me understand how to approach this problem.